# Major Tom PBS special in the 1970s?

Tags: story-identification

Hi I have fuzzy memories of a bizarre special that ran on PBS in the mid seventies in which a major tom astronaut ends up in the afterlife.  He's shown around by a little girl and sees Hitler.  That's all I remember.  Am I hallucinating or did this actually air?  Thanks

Comment: Was it [In Search of...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Search_of..._(TV_series)) It's the only 1970s reference to Hitler and astronauts I can find.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are remembering [Between Time and Timbuktu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Time_and_Timbuktu), by Kurt Vonnegut.

The astronaut was Stoney Stevenson, and the little girl was [Wanda June](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Birthday,_Wanda_June); both show up in other Vonnegut stories.